# Efficiently checking if a large enumeration has a consistent order

Tags: c#, performance, enum

The scenario is as follows: We have a streamed enumeration that we have to check if it's ordered or not before processing it (about 75-80% of the time it is ordered). We are talking about pretty big enumerations, in the range of 10-100 million elements.

Because the first step processing the data is ordering it and we need to repeat this process quite often, we obviously do not want to incur in the price of ordering the enumeration if it isn't necessary; our tests show that calling `OrderBy()` on an ordered enumeration takes, on average, about 1/3 to 1/4 of the time it takes ordering a random enumeration, so it's still a significant price we want to avoid.

So my job is to implement an efficient algorithm that checks if any given enumeration is ordered or not.

My initial goals are:

1. Make it fast, at least about 20 times faster than directly calling `OrderBy()` in the worst case scenario; the input stream is already ordered.
2. Make it as generic as possible.

The code I've come up with is:

```
public static bool IsOrdered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, T, int> comparer)
{
    using (var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            return false;

        var left = enumerator.Current;
        int previousUnequalComparison = 0;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var right = enumerator.Current;
            var currentComparison = comparer(left, right);

            if (currentComparison != 0)
            {
                if (previousUnequalComparison != 0 &&
                    Math.Sign(currentComparison) != Math.Sign(previousUnequalComparison))
                    return false;

                previousUnequalComparison = currentComparison;
            }

            left = right;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public static bool IsOrdered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return IsOrdered(list, (t, s) => t.CompareTo(s));
}
```

And I have the following performance test:

```
public static void Benchmark(int listCount, int testCount)
{
    var r = new Random();
    var randomList = GenerateRandomEnumeration(listCount, () => r.Next()).ToList();
    var watch = new Stopwatch();

    for (int j = 0; j < testCount; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test #{0}", j);

        watch.Start();
        var orderedList = randomList.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Order on random list took: {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        watch.Reset();
        watch.Start();
        orderedList = orderedList.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Order on ordered list took: {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        watch.Reset();
        watch.Start();
        var ordered = randomList.IsOrdered();
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("IsOrdered on random list: {0}", ordered);
        Console.WriteLine("IsOrdered on random list took: {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        watch.Reset();
        watch.Start();
        ordered = orderedList.IsOrdered();
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("IsOrdered on ordered list: {0}", ordered);
        Console.WriteLine("IsOrdered on ordered list took: {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine();
        watch.Reset();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Test finished.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static IEnumerable<T> GenerateRandomEnumeration<T>(int count, Func<T> randomizer)
{
    var counter = 0;

    while (counter < count)
    {
        yield return randomizer();
            counter++;
    }
}
```

The typical output, on my machine with release build and no debugger, is:

> ```
> Test #8
> Order on random list took: 6330 ms
> Order on ordered list took: 2066 ms
> IsOrdered on random list: False
> IsOrdered on random list took: 0 ms
> IsOrdered on ordered list: True
> IsOrdered on ordered list took: 144 ms
> ```

The gains are obvious. The gain in the worst case scenario is 144 ms versus 2066 ms which is about 15 times faster. Ugh! My goal is 20 times faster so close but no cigar.

Can anyone point out optimizations I might be missing that can make it faster? I think my mindset is stuck with this implementation and I might be missing something obvious.

If this is about as good as it can get, then the question is moot.

Comment: Why don't you use [`watch.Restart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.restart.aspx) instead of `watch.Reset();` followed by `watch.Start();`?

Comment: It seems slightly strange that you need to check if it's ordered, but you don't care whether it's ordered ascending or descending. Just to confirm, is that really the requirement?

Comment: @BenAaronson Yes it is, and it's not that strange; imagine that given a set of pair of values `(x, y)` you need to interpolate the value of `y` for a set of `x`. Do you really care if the set of pairs `(x, y)` is ordered ascending or descending in `x`? Or do you only care it is consistently ordered?

Comment: How unordered is your data, when it is unordered? You might benefit from using sorting algorythm, which does well for ordered or almost ordered data (Insertion sort, for example). `OrderBy` uses `QuickSort`, which is not the best for such scenario.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak I haven't analyzed it, but it there is a bit of everything. How do you confidently grade the ordering of a 1000000+ element series?

Comment: Adding to @NikitaBrizhak's comment, Wikipedia lists a couple of sorting algorithms that exhibit O(n log n) run time and work well with already-sorted data: Timsort and Cubesort for instance although I'm not familiar with those algorithms.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say *"streamed enumeration"* I assume you don't have a collection at hand and need to evaluate on-the-fly.

You can achieve a slightly performance boost (6.3% in my test below) by first determine the sort order and then branch out to test ascending/descending independently. This will decrease the number of expressions from (at worse) 3 to 1.

```
public static bool IsOrdered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, int> comparer)
{

    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {

        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            return false;
        }

        var left = enumerator.Current;
        T right;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {

            right = enumerator.Current;

            switch (comparer.Invoke(left, right))
            {

                case 0:

                    continue;

                case 1:

                    left = right;

                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {

                        right = enumerator.Current;

                        if (comparer.Invoke(left, right) < 0)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                        left = right;

                    }

                    return true;

                case -1:

                    left = right;

                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {

                        right = enumerator.Current;

                        if (comparer.Invoke(left, right) > 0)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                        left = right;

                    }

                    return true;

            }

        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

```
Avg. method #1     Avg. method #2    Avg. % difference
2788.960181        2617.859107       6.32908425031866
```

[image: Chart 1]

Now, if you want both genericism and performance then you needs to get your hands dirty. Creating typed methods for known/critical types will be a lot of work and surly increases the codebase, but the performance gained (55.5% in my test below) outweighs all of this.

```
public static bool IsOrdered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : IComparable<T>
public static bool IsOrdered(this IEnumerable<string> source)
public static bool IsOrdered(this IEnumerable<DateTime> source)
public static bool IsOrdered(this IEnumerable<short> source)
public static bool IsOrdered(this IEnumerable<ushort> source)
public static bool IsOrdered(this IEnumerable<long> source)
public static bool IsOrdered(this IEnumerable<ulong> source)
public static bool IsOrdered(this IEnumerable<uint> source)
```

...etc.

```
public static bool IsOrdered(this IEnumerable<int> source)
{

    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {

        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            return false;
        }

        int previous = enumerator.Current;
        int current;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {

            current = enumerator.Current;

            if (current == previous)
            {

                continue;

            }
            else if (current > previous)
            {

                previous = current;

                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {

                    current = enumerator.Current;

                    if (current < previous)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    previous = current;

                }

            }
            else //if (current < previous)
            {

                previous = current;

                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {

                    current = enumerator.Current;

                    if (current > previous)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    previous = current;

                }

            }

        }

    }

    return true;

}
```

```
Avg. method #1     Avg. method #2    Avg. % difference
2057.878293        1162.808066       55.5825763349346
```

[image: Chart 2]

Below is the test program.

- Add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`
- Compile (Release - Any CPU) and run the executable file.
- Paste the result into [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kringsjaa/d1few58t/) (javascript pane) to create the graph.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var size = 100000; //100000000
        var iterations = 100;

        var results = new TestResult[3]
        {
            new TestResult("Method #1"),
            new TestResult("Method #3"),
            new TestResult("Method #2")
        };

        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        var comparer = new Func<int, int, int>((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y));
        var result = false;

        IEnumerable<int> items;

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {

            // Method #1
            items = CreateEnumerator(1, size, 1);
            watch.Restart();
            result = items.IsOrdered1(comparer);
            watch.Stop();
            results[0].Milliseconds.Add(watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            results[0].Result = result;

            // Method #2
            items = CreateEnumerator(1, size, 1);
            watch.Restart();
            result = items.IsOrdered2(comparer);
            watch.Stop();
            results[1].Milliseconds.Add(watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            results[1].Result = result;

            // Method #3
            items = CreateEnumerator(1, size, 1);
            watch.Restart();
            result = items.IsOrdered3();
            watch.Stop();
            results[2].Milliseconds.Add(watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            results[2].Result = result;

            Print(results, i, iterations);

        }

        Clipboard.SetText(ToHighchart(results, size, iterations));
        Console.WriteLine("\nCompleted. Results copied to clipboard.");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public static bool IsOrdered1<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, int> comparer)
    {

        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {

            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                return false;
            }

            var left = enumerator.Current;
            int previousUnequalComparison = 0;

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {

                var right = enumerator.Current;
                var currentComparison = comparer(left, right);

                if (currentComparison != 0)
                {

                    if (previousUnequalComparison != 0 && Math.Sign(currentComparison) != Math.Sign(previousUnequalComparison))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    previousUnequalComparison = currentComparison;

                }

                left = right;

            }

        }

        return true;
    }

    public static bool IsOrdered2<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, int> comparer)
    {

        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {

            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                return false;
            }

            var left = enumerator.Current;
            T right;

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {

                right = enumerator.Current;

                switch (comparer.Invoke(left, right))
                {
                    case 0:

                        continue;

                    case 1:

                        left = right;

                        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                        {

                            right = enumerator.Current;

                            if (comparer.Invoke(left, right) < 0)
                            {
                                return false;
                            }

                            left = right;

                        }

                        return true;

                    case -1:

                        left = right;

                        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                        {

                            right = enumerator.Current;

                            if (comparer.Invoke(left, right) > 0)
                            {
                                return false;
                            }

                            left = right;

                        }

                        return true;

                }

            }

        }

        return true;
    }

    public static bool IsOrdered3(this IEnumerable<int> source)
    {

        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {

            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                return false;
            }

            int previous = enumerator.Current;
            int current;

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {

                current = enumerator.Current;

                if (current == previous)
                {

                    continue;

                }
                else if (current > previous)
                {

                    previous = current;

                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {

                        current = enumerator.Current;

                        if (current < previous)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                        previous = current;

                    }

                }
                else //if (current < previous)
                {

                    previous = current;

                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {

                        current = enumerator.Current;

                        if (current > previous)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                        previous = current;

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        return true;

    }

    private class TestResult
    {

        private List<double> milliseconds;
        private string name;

        public TestResult(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.milliseconds = new List<double>();
        }

        public List<double> Milliseconds
        {
            get
            {
                return this.milliseconds;
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.name;
            }
        }

        public bool Result { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ("{" + string.Format("name: '{0}', data: [{1}]", this.name, string.Join(", ", this.milliseconds.Select(ms => ms.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))) + " }");
        }

    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> CreateEnumerator(int start, int count, int step)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            yield return start;
            start += step;
        }

    }

    private static void Print(IEnumerable<TestResult> results, int i, int iterations)
    {

        Console.Write(string.Format("#{0}", i).PadRight((iterations.ToString().Length + 4)));

        foreach (var result in results)
        {

            if ((result != null) && (result.Milliseconds.Count > 0))
            {
                Console.Write(result.Milliseconds.Last().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).PadRight(10));
                Console.Write(result.Result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).PadRight(10));
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine();

    }

    private static string ToHighchart(IEnumerable<TestResult> result, int size, int iterations)
    {

        var title = string.Format("{0} x {1}", size, iterations);
        var data = string.Join(", ", result.Where(r => r != null).Select(r => r.ToString()));

        return @"$(function () { $('#container').highcharts({ title: { text: '" + title + "' }, exporting: { enabled: true }, xAxis: { title: 'Iterations' }, yAxis: { title: { text: 'Milliseconds' } }, credits: { enabled: false }, series: [ " + data + " ] }); });";

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

### IEnumerable<T> extension method

Your method is very fast.
Nevertheless it can be made a little bit faster:

- You are calling `Math.Sign(previousUnequalComparison)` on each iteration.
  It makes sense to store a result of `Math.Sign` in the `previousUnequalComparison` variable.
- The assignment `left = right;` can be moved into the `if (currentComparison != 0)` block.

The improved method:

```
public static bool IsOrdered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, T, int> comparer)
{
    using (var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            return false;

        var left = enumerator.Current;
        int previousUnequalComparison = 0;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var right = enumerator.Current;
            var currentComparison = comparer(left, right);

            if (currentComparison != 0)
            {
                currentComparison = Math.Sign(currentComparison);
                if (previousUnequalComparison != 0
                    && currentComparison != previousUnequalComparison)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                previousUnequalComparison = currentComparison;

                left = right;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I don't think it's possible to get better results for `IEnumerable<T>`.

---

### IList<T> parallel extension method

If it is convenient to pass a collection as `IList<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` then you could use parallelism.
Sample code:

```
public static bool IsOrderedParallel<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, T, int> comparer)
{
    // Degree of parallelism:
    int nProc = Environment.ProcessorCount;

    // Ranges for each 'thread':
    int[] mins = new int[nProc];  // Minimums (including)
    int[] maxs = new int[nProc];  // Maximums (including)
    // Arrays of results (per-thread):
    bool[] isSorted = new bool[nProc];  // true - if sorted
    int[] signs = new int[nProc];       // Order of range (-1, 0, +1)

    int prev = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nProc; i++)
    {
        mins[i] = prev;  // Ranges should overlap
        prev = maxs[i] = (i + 1) * list.Count / nProc;
    }
    maxs[nProc - 1] = list.Count - 1;

    Parallel.For(0, nProc, (index, loopState) =>
        {
            var left = list[mins[index]];
            int previousUnequalComparison = 0;
            for (int i = mins[index] + 1; i <= maxs[index] && !loopState.IsStopped; i++)
            {
                var right = list[i];
                var currentComparison = comparer(left, right);

                if (currentComparison != 0)
                {
                    currentComparison = Math.Sign(currentComparison);
                    if (previousUnequalComparison != 0 &&
                        currentComparison != previousUnequalComparison)
                    {
                        isSorted[index] = false;
                        loopState.Stop();
                        break;
                    }

                    previousUnequalComparison = currentComparison;

                    left = right;
                }
            }
            isSorted[index] = true;
            signs[index] = previousUnequalComparison;
        });

    // Return <c>true<c> if all ranges are sorted and all of them have the same order:
    return isSorted.All(r => r) && (signs.All(s => s >= 0) || signs.All(s => s <= 0));
}
```

*On my 6-core machine the last method is ~5 times faster.*